# Need to set minimal permissions for Admin using Calendar Resource API

Tags: google-app-engine, calendar, google-admin-sdk

We are building an app on App Engine to modify Calendar Resources for a client. We need an admin account setup so that we can use the Admin SDK and Calendar Resources API specifically. A full Super Admin can create new Resources, but any more restricted Admin seems to fail at creating new ones. Is there any way we can narrow the scope of permissions for an Admin user to use the Calendar Resources API specifically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only super admins can create/manage resources. However, if you are using OAuth 2.0 and the resource calendar scope which is:

```
https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/calendar/resource/
```

then the access / refresh token that you generate will be restricted to performing resource calendar API operations. The token itself won't be able to, for example, create users, change settings, etc.

Generate the token as a super admin and then make sure your AppEngine instance only has that token, not the super admin user/password.

Comment: Do you have an example by chance of how to create the Oauth2 workflow and tokens for this? The example here shows using a plain text u/n and p/w to work with this.

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/calendar-resource/#creating_a_new_calendar_resource

Comment: I got this implemented using our Framework, and works like a charm. Thanks again Jay Lee.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Data Calendar Resource API is now deprecated and is scheduled for sunset in January 2017. Apps should instead use the [Directory API's Calendar Resource object](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/resources/calendars).